# Earth Orbitting the Sun simulation Object Array not printing correctly java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to simulate the Earths orbit around the sun making it print out its current position. I'm very new to java and unable to print the "newP" array correctly within the loop. At the moment I'm using-

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newP));
```

I've also tried:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newP));
```

To no avail. I've definitely also imported java util array as well, I'm not sure why its not working. No other errors are appearing in the code either. The loop of the code is below:

```
do{ 
        PhysicsVector[] y = new PhysicsVector[gravField.length];
        y=copyArray(gravField);

        for(int i=0; i<planets.length;i++){
            newP[i] = planets[i].updatePosition(position[i], velocity[i], timeStep, gravField[i]);

        }

        for(int j=0; j<gravityObject.length; j++){    
            for(int l=0;l<gravityObject.length;l++){
                if(j!=l){
                    newGrav[j].increaseBy(gravityObject[j].aDueToGravity(planetMass[l], newP[l], newP[j]));

                }
             }
        }

        for(int k=0; k<planets.length; k++){
            newVel[k] = planets[k].updateVelocity(velocity[k], timeStep, y[k], newGrav[k]);
        }



        time+=timeStep;
        double x = newP[0].getX();
        double ap = newP[0].getY();
        n.println(x+"   "+ap);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newP));

   }while (timeStep<(24*60*60*365.25));
```

The output I get when trying to print array in the loop is the below

```
[PhysicsVector@15db9742, PhysicsVector@6d06d69c, PhysicsVector@7852e922]
[PhysicsVector@15db9742, PhysicsVector@6d06d69c, PhysicsVector@7852e922]
[PhysicsVector@15db9742, PhysicsVector@6d06d69c, PhysicsVector@7852e922]
[PhysicsVector@15db9742, PhysicsVector@6d06d69c, PhysicsVector@7852e922]
```

The output I'm expecting is a list of vectors.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is likely because PhysicsVector has no toString method. If it's your class, add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the output of the default `toString()` implementation as defined in the `java.lang.Object` class. To get a different output you have two main options

- override `toString()` in the PhysicsVector class to return some kind of formatted String of the objects contents. That just involves adding a method to the PhysicsVector class like...

  ```
  public class PhysicsVector {
      ....
      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return "PhysicsVector[" + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + "]";
      }
  ```
- convert the PhysicsVector[] into a String[] using some kind of map. In Java8 this might look like

  ```
  final String[] outputArray = Arrays.stream(newP).map((p) -> "PhysicsVector[" + p.getX() + ", " + p.getY() + "]").toArray()
  ```

If you're not using Java8 you might need to use a loop...

```
final String[] outputArray = new String[newP.length]
for (int i = 0; i< newP.length; i++) {
    outputArray[i] = "PhysicsVector[" + newP[i].getX() + ", " + newP[i].getY() + "]";
}
```